# Where are Graphite's configuration file(s) located?

Tags: ubuntu, configuration, ubuntu-14.04, graphite

We have installed graphite-web-0.9.10 on ubuntu 14. All documentation and tutorials specify /opt/graphite/conf as the config directory. However, on our server there is not even an /opt/graphite folder. The documentation seems a bit dated (2012). Specifically, I'm looking for the /opt/graphite/conf/storage-schemas.conf file.

Answer (score 0):

Just found it in /etc/carbon/storage-schemas.conf.